# Scaling UI to fit application window using JavaFX and SceneBuilder 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scaling, scenebuilder

We're currently developing a social media platform as a project at school (to be handed in in 2 weeks), and we've ran into some issues when trying to get the UI to scale with the application window. Currently it works as supposed when previewing it in SceneBuilder (see the first link) , but it seems to be stuck in the upper left corner when running the actual application via IntelliJ IDEA. I've also linked a screenshot of how it's actual behavior is (second link).

[This is how the scaling should work, and as you can see it does work when i use SceneBuilder's preview function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epxhJ.png)

[This is how the scaling is working when we run the app, which isn't scaling at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alLlN.png)

At the moment we're just trying to understand whats wrong, therefore our only focus is the 'discover page' of the platform (you access the page from the events page). So i will post the fxml code for the discover page as well as the events controller. Bare in mind this is my first ever post on here, so if there's anything else that could help you help us just tell me and i'll get it uploaded! Here is a screenshot of all the classes in our project, if there's any other class that would be helpful if i post just say the word :)

[All classes in the project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oATaO.png)

FXML for the Discover page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane fx:id="borderPaneDiscover" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="JavaFX.DiscoverController">
   <center>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="900.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TableView fx:id="tableViewDiscover" layoutY="62.0" onMouseClicked="#showDetails" prefHeight="331.0" prefWidth="900.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="65.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="eventNameColumnDiscover" minWidth="180.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Event name" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="eventLocationColumnDiscover" minWidth="180.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Event location" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="eventDateColumnDiscover" minWidth="180.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Event date" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="eventCategoryColumnCategory" minWidth="180.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Event category" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="eventCreatorColumnDiscover" minWidth="180.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Event Creator" />
              </columns>
               <columnResizePolicy>
                  <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
               </columnResizePolicy>
            </TableView>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="Choose category of the event:" textAlignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
            <ChoiceBox fx:id="choiceBoxDiscover" layoutX="375.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="375.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="375.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0" />
            <Button fx:id="buttonGo" layoutX="505.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showTableDiscover" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: #313131; -fx-text-fill: #FFF; -fx-font-weight: BOLD;" text="Go" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0">
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="145.0" prefWidth="900.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TextArea fx:id="textAreaDescription" editable="false" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="120.0" prefWidth="250.0" wrapText="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="60.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="590.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0" />
            <TextArea fx:id="textAreaParticipants" editable="false" layoutX="360.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="120.0" prefWidth="250.0" wrapText="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="290.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0" />
            <Button fx:id="attendButton" layoutX="660.0" layoutY="45.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#attendEvent" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: #313131; -fx-text-fill: #ffffff; -fx-font-weight: BOLD;" text="Attend" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="45.0">
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect>
            </Button>
            <Text layoutX="65.0" layoutY="15.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-size: 14; -fx-font-weight: BOLD;" text="Description:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="60.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Segoe UI Symbol" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text layoutX="365.0" layoutY="15.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-font-size: 14; -fx-font-weight: BOLD;" text="Participants:" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="457.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Segoe UI Symbol" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </bottom>
   <top>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="900.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="315.0" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="289.0" text="Discover events" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Button alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutX="833.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#BackToEvents" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: #313131; -fx-text-fill: #FFF; -fx-font-size: 14; -fx-font-weight: BOLD;" text="Back" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Segoe UI Symbol" size="20.0" />
               </font>
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

FXML for the events page:

```
package JavaFX;

import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import java.io.IOException;

public class EventsController {
    private ObservableList<String> usersChoice = FXCollections.observableArrayList("My events(attended/to attend and created)", "Discover(search by category and attend)", "Create event");

    @FXML
    private BorderPane eventsPane;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox <String> choicebox;

    @FXML
    private Label labelOfUserChoice;

    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        choicebox.setItems(usersChoice);

        //choicebox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(changeListener);
    }

    @FXML
    private void changeLabel() throws IOException/*, InterruptedException*/{

        switch (choicebox.getValue()) {

            //ask sokol about it

            case ("My events(attended/to attend and created)"):
                labelOfUserChoice.setText("You have chosen: " + choicebox.getValue());
                choicebox.setDisable(true);
                //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                loadMyEvents();
                break;
            case ("Discover(search by category and attend)"):
                labelOfUserChoice.setText("You have chosen: " + choicebox.getValue());
                choicebox.setDisable(true);
                //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                loadDiscover();
                break;
            case ("Create event"):
                labelOfUserChoice.setText("You have chosen: " + choicebox.getValue());
                //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                loadCreateEvent();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("YOU'VE BETTER LEARN HOW TO USE JFX!");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void goToMainMenu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/resources/mainMenu.fxml"));
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        eventsPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }

    @FXML
    private void goToProfile(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/resources/profile.fxml"));
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        eventsPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }

    @FXML
    private void goToFriends(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/friendsPage.fxml"));
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/resources/friendsPage.fxml"));
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        eventsPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }

    @FXML
    private void goToChat(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/chatclient/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        eventsPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }

    private void loadMyEvents() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/resources/myEvents.fxml"));
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        eventsPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }

    private void loadDiscover() throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/resources/discover.fxml"));
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        eventsPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }

    private void loadCreateEvent() throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/resources/createEvent.fxml"));
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        eventsPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }

}
```

So far i've read probably all the posts in here that are issues remotely like ours, but none of them have seemed to work. I haven't been able to find a post stating the exact same issue as ours, where the preview window in SceneBuilder works as supposed and the program when we run it doesn't. I hope someone can help us out, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please post [mcve]. On one hand there is probably no need for so much code to demonstrate descaling behavior. On the other hand the code is not complete so the problem can not be verified. That what mcve's are for. (Did you set `primaryStage.sizeToScene();`  ?)

Comment: I think you might have just solved the issue with `primaryStage.sizeToScene();`because we have that on the front page (which is working) but we don't have it anywhere else? We created the front page using code, but the rest was just created using SceneBuilder only which might have caused the issue. Will test it and see if that fixes the issue, thanks alot! 
PS: i will make sure to use mcve's next time, i see why this can be rather confusing :)

Comment: I am glad it helped